# What is the correct behavior expected of an HTTP POST => 302 redirect to GET?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-codes

What is the correct behavior expected of a POST => 302 redirect to GET?

In chrome (and likely most every browser), after I POST (to a resource that wants me to redirect) and I receive a 302 redirect, the browser automatically issues a GET on the 302 location. This is even a [well known pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). But the way I read the spec, it seems to suggest this should not happen.

[The HTTP spec says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3)

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent **MUST NOT automatically redirect** the
>   request **unless it can be confirmed by the user**, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

And fiddler is showing:

```
REQUEST 1: POST URLA
RESPONSE 1: 302 redirect to URLB
REQUEST 2: GET URLB
```

The section above seems to say that the browser should not make the GET request? What am I missing?

1. Something earlier in the spec that makes this section irrelevant
2. My understanding of automatically redirect is wrong (and the chrome browser that did the GET wasn't really automatically redirecting)
3. My understanding of confirmed this as a user
4. Something else?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The very next line in the spec begins:

> Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
>         to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
>         existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
>         response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>         of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have
>         been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
>         kind of reaction is expected of the client.

And immediately after that, it explains how a 303 should be handled, and it's exactly what you're seeing.

---

If you're asking why servers are still using 302 instead of 307, which all current browsers will handle correctly, it's because old browsers won't handle it. If you're wondering why browsers handle 302 as 303, it's because old servers expect it. There's really no way out of that loop, and it would probably be better for HTTP to just revert 302 to mean what it used to mean, and deprecate it (for non-GET/HEAD) in favor of 307.

Comment: abarnet: please clarify what you mean by "old browsers".

Comment: @JulianReschke: I don't know exactly. If I had to guess, I'd guess the vintage is around IE6 and FF 1.9. But remember that desktop browsers (and WebKit mobile browsers) aren't the only user-agents out there; there's plenty of people using other devices that have browsers in them, hand-coded web service clients or scraping tools, etc.

Comment: @JulianReschke: Also, I should have mentioned that 303 and 307 are in HTTP/1.1 only. There are plenty of servers and caches out there (and some user-agents) that either can't handle 1.1, or disable it. Meanwhile, I just found [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx) from the IE team that looks relevant.

Comment: FF 1.9 seems irrelevant to me. IE6 *does* support 307. At the end of the day, you will always find *some* client that is broken, so you need to draw a line.

Comment: @JulianReschke: I'm not saying your server should abuse 302, I'm explaining why many servers still do. As long as all new browsers handle the broken behavior right (and they do), and there are any old browsers that require the broken behavior, servers will continue to abuse it. This isn't a good thing, but it's a fact.

Answer (score 3):

[abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) was right ! I had the same issue with Google App Engine but I found a different solution.

My issue with appengine was,I did a POST with a form to a GO formHandler at backend. But it was executed as follow.

request 1: GET /formHandler -> response 1: 302 Found

request 1: POST /formHandler -> response 1: 302 Found

request 1: GET /formHandler -> response 1: 200 Ok.

Additionaly I got

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Which was a CORS problem.

However the solutions turns out to be to use HTTP**S** instead of HTTP.

Then you will have

request : POST /formHandler -> response : 200 Ok

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22.html#rfc.section.6.4.p.3, which tries to clarify the situation.

> Note: In HTTP/1.0, the status codes 301 (Moved Permanently) and 302 (Found) were defined for the first type of redirect ([RFC1945], Section 9.3). Early user agents split on whether the method applied to the redirect target would be the same as the original request or would be rewritten as GET. Although HTTP originally defined the former semantics for 301 and 302 (to match its original implementation at CERN), and defined 303 (See Other) to match the latter semantics, prevailing practice gradually converged on the latter semantics for 301 and 302 as well. The first revision of HTTP/1.1 added 307 (Temporary Redirect) to indicate the former semantics without being impacted by divergent practice. Over 10 years later, most user agents still do method rewriting for 301 and 302; therefore, this specification makes that behavior conformant when the original request is POST.