# Send POST data with RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my application I want to send all request in index.php where I choose which controller and method to use and call that method and give the parameter received through get or post.
So in root director I put an .htaccess file with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [QSA,L,NC,PT]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [QSA,L,NC,PT]
```

And i send all request to public folder where I have this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT,L,NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

It works and send all the request to index.php but the problem is that if I try to send data through POST it did't get to index.php,if I send it through get it works but let say that I have a login page,I can't afford to send all the data through get because I don't want the password to be seen in url.

So is there a way to send POST data to index.php with .htaccess file?

I know that there are other question like this one on site but I tried evry one of them and did'nt work,many of them answer said to add P in [] on .htaccess file but if I do that I get an error that I have made a bad request.

Comment: what do you mean it didn't get to index.php? codeigniter and in fact many other frameworks do this exact thing, and they work just fine.

Comment: I am not using any framework,I try to implement my own framework,and I mean that if I have a form with method POST when .htaccess rewrite the url to index.php the data is lost.I have a form with:  method="post" class="minimal" action='user/login' with two field username and password, user means that I need userController and login is the controller method and this method has two parameters username and password.How can I do that when .htaccess rewrite the url to index.php in index.php to have the previous url user/login  and also the username and password values from form fileds?

Comment: can you post `var_dump($_POST);` result in your login controller method?

Comment: I believe in your case .htaccess is redirecting and that is the reason the post data is lost (had the same issue with trailing slashes done bad). If you redirect the browser is sent to the destination URL before it reaches the application. Otherwise set your forms actions to the destination URI, to which you are expecting them to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I use this rewrite for apps and for now it works perfectly well:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Send the URI to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Basically the code above passes everything that is not a file or directory directly to index.php and the code sitting there has to parse it and respond accordingly.

Event with custom frameworks (as you mentioned, that you want to use your own[**Which I wouldn't advice you to do**]).

You may use restful routes and parse them in the application level, so assuming your site is on `exmaple.com` the URL is going to be something like `example.com/controller/action/`. But you need some kind of routing, to determinate the pattern.

As a reference you can look at [Slim Framework](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim), it has a very good method of defining routes, independently of what is your naming pattern for modules/controllers/actions and etc.

Comment: Thanks,I am gona look up the Slim Framework.I am not gona always use my own framework,I just made it for practice and undestand how things work in back before use a real framework,I want to use Zend 2 so I tried to implement something like MVC,I learnt from http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/  and I have a rout and helpers,but it won't use me  if the $_POST data are not send also,in the framwork you talk about when you use rewriterule and send the data to index.php is also send the $_POST values?

Comment: Ive also have done this for education purposes and lose the feeling that frameworks are pure magic.. As for Slim, it is more a meta framework, so everything is relatively simple. Make sure that everything gets passed to the index, without redirection and parse it with the app (regex, simple explode or however you find it fits).  Hope I helped :)

Comment: I used explode and the funny things is that the initial url user/login is passes to index probably with that $1 in .htaccess files,but the aren't,I will give more try and also look on Slim to see how is he doing it.Thanks!

Comment: You can double check the form action attribute and investigate the response and logs, they can give you a clue on what's going on

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov you are right about post getting lost with redirect. That is the perfect use case for http code 303. For the curious [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17605915/1273830).