# AWS: 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: amazon-web-services

I used AWS Elastic Beanstalk to setup my website. Requesting website through HTTPS is working but HTTP is responding with "400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port".

I have tried setting up an HTTP listener in load balancer to redirect HTTP to HTTPS following [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/) but did not solve the issue.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction, I'm not very familiar with AWS. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure you configure the http rule to redirect, not forward, to https. You'll need to share more details on the http listener.

Comment: By default VPC link uses port 80 as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698009/integrating-aws-api-gateway-http-type-to-private-alb-via-vpclink

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP listener must be configured to redirect requests with all components present in the request (path, query).

**HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}**

Status code: HTTP_301 (Redirect)

[image: Listener]

Comment: Please note that redirect 301/302 won't work properly for POST requests, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893149/amazon-alb-redirect-changes-http-method-to-get