# Integrating AWS API Gateway (HTTP type) to private ALB via VPCLink

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-api-gateway

I've been using the internal ALB with AWS Gateway via VPC Link for many years but in the last few weeks, when I tried to set it up again with a new ALB via VPC Link, it is not working at all. I am getting this 400 Bad Request "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error when a request is sent to the api gateway endpoint.

I am seeing this error on the log:

```
https 2023-03-08T06:35:20.252077Z app/ALB_NAME/89894bc1xxxx 172.31.xx.xx:43599 - -1 -1 -1 400 - 382 370 "POST http://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/test HTTP/1.1" "" - - - "-" "-" "-" - 2023-03-08T06:35:20.252000Z "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
```

The POST request was sent to http protocol with 443 port -> http://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/test. This seems to be causing that error that I am seeing: "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port".
I've tried every possible ways to configure VPC Links but the requests never reach the internal ALB due to this error.

The strange thing is that the existing api gateway with the vpc link that was working fine before with the internal ALB started failing with the same error.

I am wondering if anyone is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I see your endpoint with http:// instead of https://. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: I am sending a request to https://, but in the log, I am seeing the request to http://

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and was caused by a misunderstanding on how API gateway routes requests to the ALB using VPC link. In my case this was the setup:

- Public API gateway with custom domain -> VPC link -> route traffic to a private ALB listener.

The ALB has a https listener, with ACM certificate. This listener was configured as target integration on the VPC link. The problem was that the API gateway was routing the requests as plain http but including the listener port (maybe it's normal behavior, but I dind't find any [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) about that). So the final request was something like:

```
https 2023-06-27T15:01:20.216873Z app/alb/14dd3bdaf14b00a6 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:44491 - -1 -1 -1 400 - 738 370 "POST http://custom.domain:443/webhook/ HTTP/1.1"
```

Mixing http protocol and 443 port... resulting in a 400 error. *The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port*

The solution in my case was adding a new http (port 80) listener on the ALB, and configure that listener on the VPC link as target integration. That solves the problem, the ALB is still private and the requests are still secure because the API gateway public endpoint has SSL encryption. So, no need to use https internally on the VPC.

### Update

API Gateway works indeed with https listener. Check [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-api-gateway-private-apis-integration/http-api.html) and [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-private.html).

*By default, private integration traffic uses the HTTP protocol. You can specify a `tlsConfig` if you require private integration traffic to use HTTPS*

In the `tlsConfig` field you must include the domain name, in this example `custom.domain`