# LWP::UserAgent loses content data when redirecting via POST

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I am posting JSON data to Jira, and the request is hitting CAS first. A series of redirects occur. However, after the initial request I noticed that the content is zeroed out on the first redirect. The end result is that my request reaches Jira with empty content and is unsucessful.

Short of preventing LWP::UserAgent from redirecting and following the links myself, I'm not sure what else to try. My understanding is that this is supposed to be handled by the module.

This is vaguely representative with redactions...

```
use LWP::UserAgent ();
use HTTP::Request ();
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new();
my $user_agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$user_agent->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar );

push @{ $user_agent->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';

$user_agent->ssl_opts( $ssl_cert_file_pem );
$user_agent->ssl_opts( $ssl_key_file_pem );
$user_agent->ssl_opts( $verify_hostname );
$user_agent->timeout( $timeout );

my $headers_obj = HTTP::Headers->new;
$headers_obj->header( 'Accept' => '*/*' );
$headers_obj->header( 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br' );
$headers_obj->header( 'Accept-Language' => 'en-US' );
$headers_obj->header( 'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive' );
$headers_obj->header( 'Host' => $host );

my $http_request_obj = HTTP::Request->new;
$http_request_obj->method( $method );
$http_request_obj->uri( $uri );
$http_request_obj->content_type( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$http_request_obj->content( $content );

$user_agent->default_headers( $headers_obj );

$response_obj = $user_agent->request( $http_request_obj );
```

When I dump the response, I can see that the initial request returns a 302 which is then followed successfully... it's just that the content does NOT go with each redirect. How can I get LWP::UserAgent to forward content on redirect?

Comment: Shoudn't the `ssl_opts()` be given as `key => value` ?

Comment: Apologies, the code runs fine, I just heavily redacted large portions in order to simply share the outline of what I'm doing. You are correct, and it's that way in my code.

Comment: My workaround for this issue was to add a custom header containing a copy of my json content, then add a request_prepare handler which manually updates the content of each outgoing request with the info in that custom header. It works, but it seems really dumb.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I am not so familiar with this module and how it is supposed to work. Perhaps someone more experienced can help you?  I could try to reproduce the problem if you like, but then I would need some more information like `$host` and `$uri`..

Comment: The problem is not LWP but the use of 302 for redirect instead of status code 307. Possible duplicate of [What is the correct behavior expected of an HTTP POST => 302 redirect to GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605915/what-is-the-correct-behavior-expected-of-an-http-post-302-redirect-to-get)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I already accounted for that behavior in my code. I use a request_prepare handler to simply flip it back to POST if needed. My original question was about redirects causing the http content to be empty.

Comment: @Sean: Just changing to POST does not help. A 302 means switching to GET which also involves removing the request body since a GET has no request body. Also, none of this `request_prepare` is shown in your question which suggested that you were not even aware of the wrong status code used by the server (and that's why I've marked it as duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is appropriate behaviour for a 302 response.

What RFC 7231, the current HTTP spec, says the following about 302 responses:

> Note: For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
>   method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this
>   behavior is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code
>   can be used instead.

When LWP receives a 302 response to a POST made redirectable, it follows up with a GET request (which necessarily doesn't include the POST data of the original request).