# POST API not working on Heroku when accessed via own domain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku

I have a Spring Boot app running on Heroku and I am facing a weird problem.

If I try to access `https://appname.herokuapp.com/authentication/token` which is a `POST` request it works as expected with no problem.

However, I have configured my DNS and Heroku app to work on `myxyzappdomain.com` too and for most part it does. I can access the `index.html` page and all `GET` APIs. But, If I try to access any `POST` API like the one above (`https://myxyzappdomain.com/authentication/token`) I get a 405 error -

```
2020-08-17T19:47:31.039889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/authentication/token" host=www.myxyzappdomain.com request_id=92dbc99e-ed32-4643-abdb-7a0a8b6828f1 fwd="27.56.186.133,141.101.98.19" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=17ms status=405 bytes=287 protocol=http
2020-08-17T19:47:31.028327+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-17 19:47:31.028 DEBUG 4 --- [io-57518-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/authentication/token", parameters={}
2020-08-17T19:47:31.031695+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-17 19:47:31.031 DEBUG 4 --- [io-57518-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler com.abc.xyz.globalexceptions.GlobalExceptionHandler#handleException(Exception, WebRequest)
2020-08-17T19:47:31.031869+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-17 19:47:31.031  WARN 4 --- [io-57518-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
2020-08-17T19:47:31.033581+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-17 19:47:31.033 DEBUG 4 --- [io-57518-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : No match for [*/*], supported: []
2020-08-17T19:47:31.037345+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-17 19:47:31.037 DEBUG 4 --- [io-57518-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
2020-08-17T19:47:31.037484+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-17 19:47:31.037 DEBUG 4 --- [io-57518-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

Notice how it is trying to accept the `POST` request as a `GET` one and failing to do so. What is happening here?

Comment: Is there maybe something in the middle (reverse proxy? load balancer? CDN? DNS provider redirect?) that redirects your request using a 302 status code? For example redirecting `http://` to `https://`, or adding a trailing slash, or redirecting `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`, or something like that? In that case, the POST would be turned into a GET and the body dropped.

Comment: ...Yep, seems like it. I spotted `host=www.myxyzappdomain.com` in your output (note the `www`) but your question said you use `https://myxyzappdomain.com/authentication/token` (_without_ `www`).

Comment: I have Cloudflare in between acting as DNS. How do I fix that?

Comment: If it's really the `www` redirect - hm normally CloudFlare shouldn't do that by default, as far as I know, unless you explicitly configured it. It is hard to say from here what exactly is doing the redirect, I would need to know the _actual_ domain to test it, but you could also try a `curl -I https://myxyzappdomain.com/` in your shell and see if you can understand from the headers what is redirecting you. And maybe doublecheck settings in CF. Of course you can also avoid the issue by just using the final `https://www.myxyzappdomain.com/` URL (_with_ `www`) in your request in the first place.

Comment: So I have configured Cloudflare explicitly to do that because otherwise typing in the actual domain (audiotime.in) was not working; I had found an SO answer which solved it by adding `www` iin CF.

Comment: OK then the best thing you can do is use `https://www.audiotime.in` in your request instead of `https://audiotime.in`.

Comment: This worked! Please add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear you have a "middle-man" (according to your comments: a CloudFlare configuration) that redirects from the naked domain `myxyzappdomain.com` to `www.myxyzappdomain.com`.

You wrote that you use the URL `https://myxyzappdomain.com/authentication/token`, yet in your log output it says `host=www.myxyzappdomain.com` (note the `www`). That means that a redirect has taken place, probably using status code 302. [Although this was originally not defined this way in the HTTP spec, nowadays virtually all clients change the request method to `GET` when a 302 redirect is received from a `POST` request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605915/what-is-the-correct-behavior-expected-of-an-http-post-302-redirect-to-get).

For entering a URL in the browser this is not a problem, because it will be a `GET` request in the first place, but for API usage it is.

To avoid this issue, you can send your `POST` request to the final URL of the redirect in the first place - to `https://www.myxyzappdomain.com/authentication/token` (*with* `www`), so there won't be any redirect messing with your HTTP method.